# How to filter SelectList contents

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How to filter the SelectList so that I only get ClassifierElements where Classifier.Name == "CellTypes"? Is it even doable? Should I use a different kind of object like IEnumerable?

In CellController:

```
ViewData["TypeId"] = new SelectList(_context.ClassifierElements, "Id", "Name");
```

Here are the objects:

```
public class Cell
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int TypeId { get; set; }
    public ClassifierElement Type { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Component> Components { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Parameter> Parameters { get; set; }
}


public class Classifier
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ClassifierElement> ClassifierElements { get; set; }
}

public class ClassifierElement
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int ClassifierId { get; set; }
    public Classifier Classifier { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }     
}
```

Comment: `_context.ClassifierElements.Where(e => e.Name == "CellTypes")` have you tried anything like that?

Comment: @ADyson Wow it worked! (e => e.Classifier.Name == "CellTypes"). Thank you very much! Now I realize that classifiers actually need to be defined beforehand, not by the user.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Linq expression to filter the list:

```
_context.ClassifierElements.Where(e => e.Name == "CellTypes")
```